# Choose Original Magmi vs Understanding Magmi

Tags: magmi

I just want to know what are you guys using Magmi tool?

I heard that original version is easy to be attacked from hackers so i have to change the directory name or set the access privilege but UnderstandingE version has login system to protect this security problem.
Btw i can't believe that version because they know my password what if i use this tool.

So what do you think of that?

Answer (score 1):

you can allow `sitename.com/magmi path` only to your IP, in this way, it is secure
. please scan your site with this tool : http://magereport.com/ to check security.....

Answer (score 0):

you can just protect the access to magmi with the Apache utility "htpasswd" that provides basic HTTP authentication through your own web server.

here the link to the official documentation:
see "Getting it working" paragraph for how to to enforce it.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html#page-header